# php/mysql possible to return data not in database?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry I know the question sounds very weird, so let me try to explain.

**Background Info:**

I have created several columns with titles ranging from C1, C2,C3,C4, C5, Average, and Target.  Each title exists as a separate row in a MYSQL database.

You can delete any of the C1-C5 columns but you can never go higher than C5.  Deleting a column also erases the respective row from the database.  Creating a column will call a function to create a missing column from C1-C5, and create its respective row into the database.

My problem is that I want to be able to "rename" C1-C5 columns into any currently non-existing column.  I made the titles C1-C5 into select bars, and I want the info appearing under each select bar to only show what available column it can change to.

Right now I have a select bar that only shows all of the items that currently exist.  My MYSQL query looks like `SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE case_id = '$caseid'`.  Obviously that's why the select bar only shows currently existing column names.

**The Actual Question:**

Is there a way I can grab the non-existing column names and put it into a mysql result?  The reason i ask is because right now I'm storing the queried result and using a `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` to put the values into a select bar.  I could keep using that method if my query could instead return any missing (C1-C5) values in the database.

Comment: uh, deleting a column deletes a row? You should **NOT** be dynamically changing table structures like this... it's one thing to add fields as business needs change, but dropping/creating columns this frequently is just insane.

Comment: @MarcB I was confused for a second here, but I think "deleting a column" is referring to some table structure in his application not in his database.  This question would be much clearer if we had the structure of the 'table' table.

Comment: I agree with @MarcB.  This syntax might help you if you insist:  select if(colX='someval','return this val if true','return this value if false') arbitrary_name_of_column

Comment: What you want is probably possible. But like other commentators I think you should edit your question to make things much more clear in order to obtain accurate answers. You could for example show your table structure (CREATE TABLE) as well as some actual data. As an advice, you should perhaps focus on the database part in your request, since, as you've seen it, as soon as you talk about your "application background", there is some confusion between what you call row or columns. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to use the following query:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE case_id = '$caseid'
union select 'c1' union select 'c2' union select 'c3' 
union select 'c4' union select 'c5'
```

Comment: I believe this almost has it!  Testing it out, it returns everything